# dynamic web project path

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, web, path

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse, that is using some config files, but as I found out Eclipse(Juno) uses the  eclipse folder as a root folder for dynamic web projects(tried creating a new project, same result), this is not the case for normal java projects however. My question: How can I change the root folder of a dynamic web project to a given path(the actual folder of the project for an example)? Thanks!